# How to send location data to waze mapping

Tags: waze

I  am traying to send location info to waze and all other user can see I want to send location via http post or get request , how can I do it ?

Comment: This is a really vague question. Can you please provide more detail in your question? Are you trying to share your own location to multiple people? Are you trying to add permanent locations to the Waze Map? Are you trying to add notifications in the app?

Comment: i have app that willing to send location data to waze, I don't know the string structure and where to send

Comment: I want to send  location data from my php web site application to waze website in order to share location similar as waze app does.  Every waze user will able to see the location that i sent on waze website which is  open to public